# Trim argument in mean() when number of observations is odd

Tags: r, mean, trim

I need some clarification about the `trim` argument in the function `mean()`.

In `?mean` we find that

> `trim` is the fraction (0 to 0.5) of observations to be trimmed from each end of `x` before the mean is computed

> If `trim` is non-zero, a *symmetrically* trimmed mean is computed

I assume that it will trim the values symmetrically, taking as many observations from the lower range of values as from the upper.

My question is, if `x` has an odd number of observations, and if we set `trim = 0.5`, will it remove one less observation in order to cut the same ones from both sides? Or will it just take one extra out randomly either from the top or the bottom?

Thanks in advance,

Ines

Comment: hey, good question, what did your experiment show?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know the answer to your question, but I tested with this:

```
vec <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 51))
mean(vec)
# 0.5049505
mean(vec, trim = .1)
# 0.5061728
```

So in this case it seems that the function trimmed one low value before